# How to add in missing dates as rows in table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I have the following code which gets me how many rows were written on each day there was anything done.

```
SELECT
  ingestion_time,
  COUNT(ingestion_time) AS Rows_Written,
FROM
  `workday.ingestions`
GROUP BY
  ingestion_time
ORDER BY
  ingestion_time
```

Which will give me something that looks like the following:

| Ingestion_Time | Rows_Written |
| --- | --- |
| Jan 2, 2021 | 8 |
| Jan 5, 2021 | 5 |
| Jan 8, 2021 | 9 |
| Jan 9, 2021 | 2 |

However, I want to be able to add in the missing dates so the tables looks like this instead:

| Ingestion_Time | Rows_Written |
| --- | --- |
| Jan 2, 2021 | 8 |
| Jan 3, 2021 | 0 |
| Jan 4, 2021 | 0 |
| Jan 5, 2021 | 5 |
| Jan 6, 2021 | 0 |
| Jan 7, 2021 | 0 |
| Jan 8, 2021 | 9 |
| Jan 9, 2021 | 2 |

How can I go about doing this? Do need to create a whole table with all dates and join it somehow, or is there another way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add tag for database platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select date(Ingestion_Time) Ingestion_Time, Rows_Written 
from your_current_query union all
select day, 0 from (
  select *, lead(Ingestion_Time) over(order by Ingestion_Time) next_time 
  from your_current_query
), unnest(generate_date_array(date(Ingestion_Time) + 1, date(next_time) - 1)) day
```

if to apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]